# public url different to behind the scenes url

Tags: php, .htaccess, oop, url-rewriting, get

How do I allow a user to navigate to this url *example.com/aaron-cole-about*, and behind the scenes it changes it to this url to *example.com/about?id=52*, but still shows this url on the browser *example.com/aaron-cole-about*

tried this on my .htaccess file, but i didn't seem to work:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/aaron-cole-about$ /about?id=52 [L]
```

fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to re-order your rules.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/aaron-cole-about$ /about?id=52 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

What was happening, is it was matching the `(.*)` — a.k.a. match anything — rule, which makes your more specific rule unreachable.

Comment: doesn't work got a 500 internal server error now, http://www.starsqa.com/aaron-cole-about and http://www.starsqa.com/about?id=52 also this one too. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA] (takes a .php out the end of the url)

Comment: whole site has a 500 internal server error btw, added new .htaccess above

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.  Does anyone else see my error?

Comment: got rid of 500 internal server error from all pages but aaron-cole-about page, see above

Comment: You should probably ask the PHP part of the question on a different question (keeps things organized, and I can't help with that code).

Comment: ok thanks, taken out the mentions of PHP stuff from this question

Comment: fixed it RewriteRule ^aaron-cole-about\.php$ /about?id=52 [L] we hadn't removed .php until afterwards

Comment: Yes, but you should put a canonical meta tag on the page, so google doesn't register it as duplicate content.

Comment: i don't suppose you know how to fix this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160168/why-am-i-getting-a-500-error-page-instead-of-a-404-error-page-when-removing-php

Comment: fixed other issue now :-)